# How can I catch asynchronous-non-promised errors ? ( react to that specific error)

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

*I know that there are  answers out there but I didn't find a specific answer to my actual question.*

Currently I [*use*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20class%20A%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20getLocation()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20throw%20Error(%22ffffff%22)%20%7D%2C%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.reject(2222222)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20async%20a()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20loc%20%3D%20await%20this.getLocation()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(loc)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20catch%20(e)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22catch%202%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20new%20A().a()%3B) the following pattern a lot :

```
 class A
 {
     getLocation()
     {
         return Promise.reject(2222222)
     }
     async a()
     {
         try
         {
             var loc = await this.getLocation();
             alert(loc)
         }
         catch (e)
         {
             alert("catch 2")
         }
     }
 }
 new A().a();
```

> - Result : "catch 2"

Event If I throw an error in `getLocation` :

```
  getLocation()
     {
         throw Error("ffffff")
     }
```

- I get the same result  - which is OK.

**So where is the problem ?**

Well as you know , an error which is thrown `asynchronously-non-promised` is a different beast :

So [this  code won't be catched](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20class%20A%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20getLocation()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FsetTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20throw%20Error(%22ffffff%22)%20%7D%2C%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((v%2C%20x)%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20Error(%22ffffff%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20100))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20async%20a()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20loc%20%3D%20%20await%20this.getLocation().catch(f%3D%3Ealert(%22catch1%22))%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20alert(loc)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20catch%20(e)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22catch%202%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20new%20A().a()%3B)  at all:

```
  getLocation() //bad code from a third party code , third party code
  { 
      return new Promise((v, x) => setTimeout(() =>
      {
          throw Error("ffffff")
      }, 100))
  }
```

**Question :**

Regarding the fact that I want to catch errors -  is there a better pattern for capturing this ?

Sure I can do  :

```
window.onerror = function () { alert(4)}
```

But that would be not in order as the flow of `.catch(...)` or `catch(){}` , and I won't be able to do actions regarding *that* specific action that caused error.

*Full disclosure:*
No real life scenario. Learning purpose .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an error which is thrown asynchronously-non-promised is a different beast

Yes. And it must be avoided at all costs. Therefore, **never** put business code (including trivial things like property accesses) in asynchronous non-promise callbacks. It could throw! It should be obvious that `JSON.parse` can fail, that a property access can throw when the "object" is `null` or `undefined` or a getter is involved, or that a loop can fail when the thing that was supposed to be an array has no `.length`.

The only things that are allowed as asynchronous non-promise callbacks are `resolve`, `reject`, and `(err, res) => { if (err) reject(err); else resolve(res); }` (and maybe a variadic version for weird APIs with multiple arguments).

So rewrite the bad code to

```
async getLocation() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    throw Error("ffffff");
}
```

or

```
getLocation() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)).then(res => {
        throw Error("ffffff");
    });
}
```

and when it's third-party code make them fix it, make an upstream merge request of your fix, or if those don't work abandon that party.

> is there a better pattern for capturing this?

Well, [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) (in node) were supposed to solve this problem of non-locality of asynchronous (uncaught) exceptions, but [they didn't work out](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/domain-postmortem/). Maybe some day, [zones](https://github.com/domenic/zones) with better native language support will replace them.

Answer (score 0):

The errors should be caught in place where they occur.

This kind of code code is incorrect and should be fixed in-place:

```
  getLocation() //bad code from a third party code
  { 
      return new Promise((v, x) => setTimeout(() =>
      {
          throw Error("ffffff")
      }, 100))
  }
```

If this is third-party code, it can be forked or patched.

Exceptions can be tracked globally by [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), as the question already mentions. This should be used only to notify a developer of existing errors, not to handle them in normal way.

[`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) event can be used for same purpose to notify about unhandled rejections in promises. It won't be able to handle the error in the snipped above because it is thrown inside `setTimeout` callback and doesn't result in promise rejection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the basic usage would be like this:

```js
class A {
  getLocation(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
      // a lot of async code
      try {
        //simulate unexpected exception    
        if (x === 2) {
          throw ("code error");
        }
        if (x) {
          resolve('success');
        } else {
          reject('conditional rejection');
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        reject(ex);
      }
    }, 1000));
  }
  async a(x) {
    await this.getLocation(x).then((loc) => console.info(loc)).catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }
}
let o = new A();
o.a(2);
o.a(0);
o.a(1);
```

The rejection of the `Promise` is not necessarily an code `Exception` as well as the code `Exception` should not necessarily trigger a `Promise` rejection.